# How to use Google Cloud get_operation?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, grpc, google-speech-api

I'm trying to use the `OperationsClient` `get_operation()` function so I can poll a long running task and get its status.

https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/core/operations_client.html#google.api_core.operations_v1.OperationsClient.get_operation

The code looks fairly simple:

```
api = operations_v1.OperationsClient()
response = api.get_operation(name)
```

However, the initialization of `OperationClient` requires a channel: `OperationsClient(channel)`. I am clueless as to what a [channel](https://grpc.io/grpc/python/grpc.html#grpc.Channel) does or how its created.

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From the docs you linked:

> **`channel`** (*[grpc.Channel](https://grpc.io/grpc/python/grpc.html#grpc.Channel)*) – The gRPC channel associated with the service that implements the `google.longrunning.operations` interface.

So if it's your own gRPC service, you'll want to do something like:

```
import grpc
channel = grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:50051')
api = operations_v1.OperationsClient(channel)
response = api.get_operation(name)
```

Depending on what long-running service you're trying to poll, you might need to use its channel instead.

Comment: What if its not my own gRPC service? Currently I'm just using the SpeechClient to run long_running_recognize on an audio file. I have the operation's name, just need to figure out how to poll for status.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that I ended up using.

```
operation = self.stt_client.transport._operations_client.get_operation(operation_name)
response = operation_core.from_gapic(
            operation,
            self.stt_client.transport._operations_client,
            types.LongRunningRecognizeResponse,
            metadata_type=types.LongRunningRecognizeMetadata,
        )
```

Comment: What is self.stt_client in this example? Is it google.cloud.speech.SpeechClient() ?